# If any possible to play .asx,.m3u file type in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, audio-streaming

i used background player for streaming audio.i have .m3u,.asx file type.if any possible to play in windows phone.

Comment: You should find the complete list of available codecs on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff462087(v=VS.92).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having worked with these file formats in a previous life on a WinCE5 project, I would doubt either is supported in WP7.

The good news is that both file formats are text and fairly easy to parse.

For m3u the parsing is really easy - 1 line per url with # denoting a comment.

For asx, the format is in theory well documented and easy to use. However, in practice I discovered that asx was used a little like unvalidated html is - you'll find asx files out there that just aren't valid according to the spec, but wmp plays them fine.